# Windows Phone - handle horizontal flick in flipview and vertical in parrent scrollviewer

Tags: windows-phone-8, event-handling, windows-phone, scrollviewer, windows-phone-toolkit

I am using FlipView from Kinnara's fork of Windows Phone Toolkit. I want to use it in ScrollViewer like in title. FlipView would handle flick/swipe in horizontal and ScrollViewer would work with vertical. I get it almost right but when user tries flick vertical on FlipView it doesn't do anything. I guess it's because manipulation events in flipview has e.Handled set to true. Is it right? How can I remove this when I am using toolkit by Nuget? Or is there another aproach? Thanks

Comment: To confirm that it is e.Handled, you should clone the fork and include the project into your solution. Then make the changes needed to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I was trying to but when I did it there was problem with content. Instead of showing images it shows class name like I was binding not path but whole object but I wasn't.